# Can't seem to get babel and webpack to work for ES2015, getting import error

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

My `webpack.config.js` is this:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    'babel-polyfill',
    './app/main.js'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    filename: 'build.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: '/\.vue$/',
        loader: 'vue'
      },
      {
        test: '/\.js$/',
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ExternalsPlugin('commonjs', [
      'electron'
    ])
  ]
}
```

my `.babelrc` is this

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"],
  "plugins": ["transform-runtime"]
}
```

my `./app/main.js` is this

```
import vue from 'vue';
import App from './views/App.vue';

new vue({
  el: 'body',
  components: { App }
});
```

my `package.json` dependencies are this

```
"dependencies": {
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-runtime": "^5.8.38",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "vue": "^2.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.18.2",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.7",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.15.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-runtime": "^5.8.38",
    "css-loader": "^0.25.0",
    "electron-prebuilt": "^1.4.5",
    "vue-hot-reload-api": "^2.0.6",
    "vue-html-loader": "^1.2.3",
    "vue-loader": "^9.7.0",
    "vue-style-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "webpack": "^1.13.3",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2"
  }
```

But when I try to launch my Electron program, I get this error in the console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

Which points to `Line 1` of `./app/main.js`

I've tried changing the loader to `babel` instead of `babel-loader` and I've tried a bunch of different presets, all the links are purple on the first 3 pages of google but most of them point to the same fix usually people forgetting `babel-preset-es2015` but I have done that. Any help would be great

Running Node Version 6.9.1 and NPM Version 3.10.8

[image]

Comment: Please post the full error message.

Comment: @loganfsmyth added it to the foot of the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loader `test` parameters are strings, not regular expressions. Therefore the JavaScript files never match these loaders (since a string test will be interpreted as an absolute path to compare to), and the files are never processed with Babel to begin with.

Just update your loaders to this, and Webpack should be working correctly:

```
loaders: [
  {
    test: /\.vue$/, // note no quotes
    loader: 'vue'
  },
  {
    test: /\.js$/,  // note no quotes
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    exclude: /node_modules/
  }
]
```

Comment: Oh my you're a wonderful person, I couldn't find that for the life of me, I guess thats why you don't start a project at 5AM.